# How do (stack/register) based virtual machine handle different datatypes

Tags: c, types, jvm, stack, vm-implementation

How do stack based and register based virtual machine handle different data types?

I know that stack based virtual machines use a stack to store their data and push and pop data on and off of this stack, but how do they represent this data? is it like some sort of data that can be cast to whatever is needed or are there multiple stacks, one stack for each data type such as ints, floats, objects, chars, arrays, and references? If it used multiple stacks then does it have to move things around in order to add say a float and an int?

In addition do register based virtual machines do something similar?

The JVM and Dalvik VM would be good examples if many VM do it differently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way the data in the stack is *interpreted* usually depends on the opcodes executed. E.g some are dedicated to byte or short manipulation  when some can use the stack items as longs. The stack always store the same kind of data, probably longs.

Comment: @Seki so they are all the same datatype then as your saying, but they're cast or used as different types by different opcodes?

Comment: Look into [neokvm](http://nekovm.org/) and [lua](http://lua.org/). Both are simple VMs and there source code is free software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what most bytecode interpreters and VMs do is either...

you could use a union to translate the bits into a different type, example on transforming a double to an array of chars

```
union {
    uint32_t i[2];
    double dbl;
} dbl2ints;

dbl2chars.dbl = double_value;
```

you can now use the values in `dbl2chars.i[0]` and `dbl2chars.i[1]` to emplace into whatever is holding the virtual machines memory/data. Thus if your custom language compiles to the VMs bytecode, you can have the compiler compile floats/doubles into integer values and use the correct floating point opcodes, then reinterpret the bits back as floats/doubles.

another, more popular, method (as used by Lua's VM and other VMs) is to make tagged unions.

```
typedef union {
    float fl;
    uint32_t ui;
    char *pstr;
} valuedata;

typedef struct {
    valuedata val;
    uint32_t valtype;
} ValType;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both stack-based and Register based virtual machines actually store their data the same way. Register-based virtual machines use an array of words(unsigned integers) of the chosen word size like 32 or 64 bit to represent their registers. For Stack-based virtual machines, the stack is implemented as an array of words usually 32 bit unsigned integers with a pointer to the top of the array stack.

The trick to how both these types of virtual machines actually store and handle their data is when they read and write it. For example to push a double on to the stack of a 32 bit Stack-based virtual machine the double would be read in two parts. The upper and lower halves of the double would be treated as unsigned integers and simply pushed on to the stack individually. These types of data conversions can be achieved by casting, pointers, and unions in C and C++.